# Zabbix5.0 How do I Change disk Monitoring thresholds

Tags: zabbix

For zabbix5.0, the default alarm is generated when the disk usage exceeds 80%, but I want to change the alarm to exceed 90%. How should I change the alarm? I did not find the modification, and I used the Template 'Template OS Linux by Zabbix Agent Active'.

Comment: just edit the trigger https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/triggers/trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to that host under configuration -> hosts, choose you host, click on Macros -> inherited and host macros, look for {$VFS.FS.PUSED.MAX.WARN} (default 80) and change it, you should also change {$VFS.FS.PUSED.MAX.CRIT} (default 90)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have found the modification. Thank you

Comment: For zabbix > 6 go to Data Collection - Hosts. Click hostname of the host.
Go to Macros - Inherited and host macros.